# App Crash while build in Release Mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've built an App which works fine in debug mode.
But, When it comes to Release Mode, it starts crashing and I assure there is no issue in Code / Proguard.

When My SplashActivity has **no setContentView**, it works **fine**.
But When it (setContentView) refers a Programatically Created View, it starts crashing.

In CrashLog, it mentions something weird **XML file line #95**.
But I didn't refer a xml layout file.
And CrashLog mentions **Error inflating class Button**.
I've passed Programmatically Created ImageView alone.

Code in onCreate:

```
ImageView ivSplash = new ImageView(this);
ivSplash.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
ivSplash.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash_image);

setContentView(ivSplash);
```

Even I just checked with Empty TextView, it also crashing, there is nothing relates with ImageView / Image.
Because in Release Mode, the same app works fine two days before. But Not Now.

Completely Weird. Kindly Check this & help. Please find the CrashLog in following.

Crash Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.shriramvalue.shrirampay.dev, PID: 30843
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shriramvalue.shrirampay.dev/com.shriramvalue.shrirampay.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void agv.a()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setBackgroundDrawable(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:18139)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4575)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:710)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.a(Unknown Source)
        at abs.a(Unknown Source)
        at abs.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at abs.b(Unknown Source)
        at acg.setContentView(Unknown Source)
        at abc.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:389)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:293)
        at abd.b(Unknown Source)
        at h.f(Unknown Source)
        at com.shriramvalue.shrirampay.SplashActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: `Binary XML file line #95`

Comment: there is null pointer it seems ,  when you are trying to do agv.a()

Comment: I mentioned in question already, I didn't pass any XML Layout there. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: try this -change the size of image you are using@Vivek

Comment: Tried that too @Dhanshri. Even I replaced TextView, still issue persists.
When i comment setContentView method, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Tracing Mapping.txt **`agv`** refers AppcompatButton.

In SplashActivity, I've checked RuntimePermissions and it refers AppcompatButton in AlertDialog.

So, I've included the following lines in Proguard to ensure these classes are not to be obfuscated and My Issue was resolved.

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class android.support.v7.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

But I Wonder how my app was working fine so much days without these lines are not included in Proguard and Suddenly Issue raises.

If anybody knows that mystery Please decode it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void agv.a()' on a null object reference

apply validation

```
if(agv.a()!=null)
//condition
```

also check your xml

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95:
>   Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button

at line number 37.

Comment: so what is your solution for OP? this should be as a comment when you don't provide any solution

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void agv.a()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setBackgroundDrawable(Unknown Source).
<br/>
But I didn't use AppCompatButton, I just used ImageView

Answer (score 0):

You have a proguard issue. The view class you used in your xml should be excluded from proguard.

For example in `com.example.Myview` Myview class should be excluded which you used in XML like

`<com.example.Myview`

```
-keep public class com.example.Myview
```

Comment: I've used ImageView and also in Proguard I've added

-keep public class * extends android.view.View